# Is this proof of limit of $f(x,y)$ correct?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, limits-without-lhopital

The limit is this:

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{\log\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}.$$

I think I did the proof well. Using that
$\lim\limits_{z\to\infty}\dfrac{\log(z)}{z}=0$
$,\lim\limits_{t\to 0^+}\dfrac{1}{t}=\infty$
$,\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=0,$
$ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}>0 \space$ and the characterization of limits with sequences, we obtain that $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{\log\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}=0$.

Comment: This is correct, if you notice that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is exactly the distance of point $M(x,y)$ to the origin when you choose the euclidian norm (they are all equivalent in finite dimension, so pick the one that makes your reasonings easiest :-)

Comment: Your reasoning seems correct and [Wolfram Alpha agrees with you](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+(x,+y)+approaches+(0,+0)+of+(log(1%2Fsqrt(x%5E2%2By%5E2)))%2F(1%2Fsqrt(x%5E2%2By%5E2))), so I think this proof is valid.

Comment: This is correct also notice that you could've converted to polar and it would accomplish the same thing

Comment: What you've presented is not a proof, but evaluating the limit. Yes, the answer is correct.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Wolfram Alpha can evaluate some existing limits as non-existing limits and vice versa, so, that's not a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's a fine proof, as an alternative since $\log x \le \sqrt x$ we have

$$\dfrac{\log\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}} \le \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt[4]{x^2+y^2}}=\sqrt[4]{x^2+y^2} \to 0$$

and we can conclude by squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Take, $x=r cos(\theta) , y = r sin(\theta) $

Now, we have, $$\lim_{r \to 0 } \frac{\log(\frac{1}{r})}{\frac{1}{r}} = 0 $$
So, the result,
$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{\log\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

As we have $x^2+y^2$ in our equation, it is best to convert to polar.

Let $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r$. Note I didn't give the individual equations of $x$ or $y$, unlike A Learner's answer, because we don't have any other expression with $x$ or $y$.

Let's start by setting our limit. Substituting $x=y=0$ into $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = r$, $r=0$. Therefore, we have

$$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\log(\frac{1}{r})}{\frac{1}{r}} = \lim_{r \to 0} r\log(\frac{1}{r})$$.

By Squeeze Theorem and $\log(x)\leq\sqrt{x}$, $$\lim_{r \to 0} r\log(\frac{1}{r})\leq \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{r}{\sqrt{r}}= \lim_{r \to 0} \sqrt{r} = 0.$$

But overall, your proof is solid.

Comment: How is your answer any different than user's and A Learner's answer?

Comment: He used direct calculation, however I used Squeeze Theorem.